# Why does PyInstaller exe has the machine path where the exe get built?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

i used pyinstaller to have an exe app, and now when I transfer that exe to another PC it showed the developer paths while it is importing the modules, (The app running well I just wondered why he has the developer PC path)

Let's say we have developer and client:
We build the app with PyInstaller on the developer's PC.
Then I send that exe to the client, he runs it and let's say he has an error in some modules it will show like this:

Traceback  file main.py, line ... File C:\Users\ **developer**\ .......\someModule.py line ..., in ....

Why it is not C:\Users\ **Client** \ ....\ .....

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Ever get this resolved?